# Where can I put this getdate() call?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Where can I put this `getdate()` call in the following statements:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
    (@email nvarchar(50), @password nvarchar(50))
AS
    SELECT employee_id, position 
    FROM tbl_employee_tbl 
    WHERE email = @email AND login_password = @password

    INSERT INTO tbl_log_activity(employee_id, sign_in_time) 
        SELECT 
            employee_id 
        FROM 
            tbl_employee_tbl,getdate() 
        WHERE 
            email = @email
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3):

Change the second statement this way:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_log_activity(employee_id,sign_in_time) 
SELECT employee_id, Getdate() 
FROM tbl_employee_tbl
WHERE email=@email
```

Comment: **ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_test](@email nvarchar(50),@password nvarchar(50))
  as
  select employee_id,position from tbl_employee_tbl where email=@email and    login_password= @password

 insert into tbl_log_activity(employee_id,sign_in_time) select employee_id,select FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd/mm/yyyy,hh:mm:ss') as date from tbl_employee_tbl where email=@email**

Answer (score 1):

```
create procedure 
sp_test(@email nvarchar(50),@password nvarchar(50)) 
as 
select 
    employee_id,
    position 
from 
    tbl_employee_tbl 
where
     email=@email and login_password= @password

insert into 
    tbl_log_activity(employee_id,sign_in_time) 
    select 
        employee_id 
        ,getdate()
    from 
        tbl_employee_tbl 
    where email=@email
```

Comment: ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_test](@email nvarchar(50),@password nvarchar(50))
  as
  select employee_id,position from tbl_employee_tbl where email=@email and    login_password= @password

 insert into tbl_log_activity(employee_id,sign_in_time) select employee_id,select FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd/mm/yyyy,hh:mm:ss') as date from tbl_employee_tbl where email=@email

Comment: @JibinBalachandran DataType of "sign_in_time" is DateTime and its format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnn]

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

`FORMAT()` function won't work in SQL Server 2008, so you can go for `CONVERT()`.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_test]
(
 @email nvarchar(50),
 @password nvarchar(50)
) 
as 

select employee_id,position 
from tbl_employee_tbl 
where email=@email and login_password= @password 

insert into tbl_log_activity(employee_id,sign_in_time) 
select employee_id,convert(varchar(25), GETDATE(),131) as date
from tbl_employee_tbl 
where email=@email
```

**Note:** But I would recommend you not to store date with any format in the database. Store it as datetime and whenever you want that to access that value, you can format it in the select query and display it according to our need.

Still if you want to store date withspecific format in db make sure that you have sign_in_time column as varchar(25).

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
(@email nvarchar(50), @password nvarchar(50))
AS
SELECT employee_id, position 
FROM tbl_employee_tbl 
WHERE email = @email AND login_password = @password

INSERT INTO tbl_log_activity(employee_id, sign_in_time) 
    SELECT 
        employee_id ,getdate()
    FROM 
        tbl_employee_tbl 
    WHERE 
        email = @email
```